# Custom UI and parameters on Managed package install

Tags: metadata

I am developing an application that can be isntalled as a managed package.

I want the customers to be presented with some UI during the package install that would let them configure some values my app works with, specifically the picklist values.

What's the best way to implement this?

(Or, if someone has any technical info on how to leverage this: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2017/07/build-powerful-setup-apps-new-apex-metadata-api.html)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control the installation screen and standard content that Salesforce has during managed package installation.

However the best practice all the apps follow is they have a custom page (either as a visualforce page or lightning component ) called config page or settings page.Settings page can have all the instructions and settings and typically accessed by the admin installing the applications .

You can even attach setting page to the [config option](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading.htm) so that your customers can click config link on the package and land on to the visualforce page .

Comment: What about the `beautiful Setup Apps` that are promised here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2017/07/build-powerful-setup-apps-new-apex-metadata-api.html?

Comment: They are talking same thing use custom metadata api of apex and build a component to keep all config in one place .

Comment: so how do i build this component? where do i click in the salesforce UI to assign this component to package?

Comment: @zaitsman Looks at docs here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading.htm . You will build a custom lightning page with apex and then package this up as a part of package and provide url link in the configure link during upload

Comment: I have read that prior to asking the question, that is very vague and non-specific to what i am trying to do. Further, the user is not required to do this, meaning they can skip clicking on the link so my app will not function. It seems weird that SF would not allow a mandatory custom step like this...