# Is it possible to pass parameters into PostInstallScript?

Tags: postinstall, package-install

The idea is to add parameters to the package installation link, for example:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04txxxxxxxxxxxx&cutom_param=some_value
```

And then use this parameter in PostInstallScript.

Is it possible to pass any values this way?

I have read this question and the solution here is not quite appropriate for me ([Custom UI and parameters on Managed package install](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251520/custom-ui-and-parameters-on-managed-package-install)), because I need to set everything during installation and without any UI.

Comment: AFAIK is not possible to pass params```sfdx force:package:install```. One of the approach could be scheduled job's + triggers on signup request in order to set Feature parameters + make callout to external service

Comment: @kurunve That's the problem. To make a callou to external service you need to set up some Remote Site Settings. However, it is bad practice to set any RSS visibly unrelated to your package and can be refused by security check of SF.

Comment: @kurunve And second problem is, I need to know the source, for example, from which landing page my customer came. So in scheduled jobs it wil be predefined, and the idea of params is just the opposite. But thank you very much for  your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the documentation about install handler, which does not talk about anything like URL parameter over there. The InstallHandler Interface has an only method which takes a single parameter as InstallContext, below are the methods available there.

```
global interface InstallContext { 
  ID organizationId();
  ID installerId();
  Boolean isUpgrade();
  Boolean isPush(); 
  Version previousVersion();
}
```

So as of now, its something that's not possible. but you can create an Idea for it [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch)

> One possible solution could be using Config Page, as mentioned in
>   [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251520/custom-ui-and-parameters-on-managed-package-install) example. In addition to that, you can create a Default
>   setting on package installation, which later can be changed manually.

[Install Hander](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm)

[Post install script](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=apex_post_install_script_intro.htm&type=5)

Comment: Yes, sure, I am using Configuration VF now, but I was wondering, maybe, it can be done without user interaction at all, like ```...&main_theme=blue```, for example, if the person came from blue landing page. Also I thought about using something like ```ApexPages.currentPage()``` in PostInstallScript, however, no PageReference appeared.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova As of now, you will need user interaction. But if you have some basic settings which could work for the majority/all of your clients, you could put it by default and others can customize it as needed.

Comment: As I thought, thank you very much!